# How to use padding-bottom for background image without distorting image

Tags: css, image, wordpress

Alright, well here is my code:

```
#header {
    background-image: url('http://hamsoc.polymath.io/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hamsocheader.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
}
```

It scaled correctly, just like I want, but if you visit the actual image http://hamsoc.polymath.io/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hamsocheader.png you'll see that it is quite a bit more clearer than it is when it shows up on the website. Is there a different way of doing this? Is there a way to use padding-bottom with the perfect resolution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks OK on the web site. Bigger, but quality is the same. Or you don't want it to be bigger?

Comment: Right, it looks okay, but it's not the correct resolution. It's a tad blurrier than the actual image. I need to make it so it looks crystal clear..

Comment: its blurrier because you use background-size: cover; so it gets resized to fit the parent element and will kind of lose pixel color information for some parts of the image. You can use a graphic editing tool to fit exactly the size you need, provided that you have a fixed size for the element containing this background.. can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah, scaling up always distorts. You want to go from large to small, never small to large if you want it to keep a nice crisp resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was use two background images, the "logo" is fixed and I made the background image repeat horizontally and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the image resolution size